# Scope_identity() coming back with '@P11' in error. MSSQL, Coldfusion. Trying to get last inserted ID

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, scope-identity

I'm getting an error with SELECT Scope_Identity()

I'm inserting a new row of data from a Form. The row generates a auto-incemented ID(RBID).

I'm trying to immediately grab it and insert it(RBID) into another row, so it can be referenced when needed.

```
<cfquery name="recbilling" datasource="#request.dsn#" result="myResult">
INSERT INTO RBilling
(CID, UserID, DateCompleted, ClientID, Title, Qty, Rate, Taxable, Description, NextBillingDate,
FrequencyUnit, FrequencyDuration, ProjectID)
VALUES (
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#UserID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#DateCompleted#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ClientID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#text0#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#Qty#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#text2#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" value="#Taxable#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" value="#text1#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#NextBillingDate#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FrequencyUnit#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FrequencyDuration#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">)
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="getRBID" datasource="#request.dsn#">
SELECT Scope_Identity() as newID
</cfquery>
<cfset RBID = #getRBID.newID#>
</cfif>




<cfquery name="submithourssubmit" datasource="#request.dsn#">
INSERT INTO Billedfees
(CID, UserID, DateCompleted, ClientID, Title, Qty, Rate, Taxable, Description, ProjectID, RBID)
VALUES (
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#UserID#">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#DateCompleted#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ClientID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#text0#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#Qty#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#text2#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" value="#Taxable#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" value="#text1#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#RBID#">
)
</cfquery>
```

The error I'm getting is:
Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '@P11'. 
The error occurred on line 57.

It took me a while to figure out what @P11 was, but it seems like either the FrequencyUnit in the first query, or RBID in the second insert query are problematic.

Datatypes are set properly.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

SQL String
(param 1) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='15488', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER'] , (param 2) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='21066', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER'] , (param 3) = [type='IN', class='java.sql.Timestamp', value='2013-03-22 00:00:00.0', sqltype='CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP'] , (param 4) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='143933', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER'] , (param 5) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='Software Test 3', sqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR'] , (param 6) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Float', value='1.0', sqltype='CF_SQL_REAL'] , (param 7) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Float', value='33.0', sqltype='CF_SQL_REAL'] , (param 8) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Boolean', value='false', sqltype='CF_SQL_BIT'] , (param 9) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='Software Test 3', sqltype='CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR'] , (param 10) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='0', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER'] , (param 11) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='153314', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER']

Here's what I got so far:

```
<cftransaction>


<cfset NextBillingDate = #DateAdd("#FrequencyUnit#", "#FrequencyDuration#", #DateCompleted#)#>

<cfquery name="recbilling" datasource="#request.dsn#" result="myResult">
INSERT INTO RBilling
(CID, UserID, DateCompleted, ClientID, Title, Qty, Rate, Taxable, Description, NextBillingDate,
FrequencyUnit, FrequencyDuration, ProjectID)
VALUES (
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#UserID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#DateCompleted#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ClientID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#text0#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#Qty#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#text2#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" value="#Taxable#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" value="#text1#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#NextBillingDate#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FrequencyUnit#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FrequencyDuration#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">)
</cfquery>


<cfoutput>
<Cfset RBID="#myResult.identitycol#">
</cfoutput>





<cfquery name="submithourssubmit" datasource="#request.dsn#">
INSERT INTO Billedfees
(CID, UserID, DateCompleted, ClientID, Title, Qty, Rate, Taxable, Description, ProjectID, RBID)
VALUES (
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#UserID#">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#DateCompleted#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ClientID#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#text0#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#Qty#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#text2#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" value="#Taxable#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" value="#text1#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#RBID#">
)
</cfquery>
```

Which gives me the same Error:
Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '@P11'. 
The error occurred on line 59.

Line 59 is the  in the second insert query.

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks

Comment: You should not need `scope_identity` unless you are running CF7 or earlier. The identity value will be placed in your result attribute: `myResult.IDENTITYCOL`

Comment: Also, it does not look like the error has anything to do with `scope_identity`. Seems to occur before that. Can you edit your question to include the *full* error message - including the generated SQL string?

Comment: the way its being used above, I believe the p11, RBID, is passing a null value in.... see my answer below to correct it.

Comment: Quite possibly, but I was also hinting that the question does not make it clear *which* query is throwing the error -or- is near line 57 ;-) So it would help to have more information and see the generated sql.

Comment: Thanks again Leigh fro the response. You've a great help in my life lately. I tried using myResult.IDENTITYCOL and was getting the same @P11 in the error. Let me try that with some more of these suggestions, and see what I get. Line 57 is the <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#RBID#"> insert value in the second insert query. I mean't to write that too, I gotta get better at writing these questions.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes error messages "lie", so the error may be on a different line altogether. Dump the value of #RBID# before the query throwing the error. If it is a valid *integer*, then the problem may be something else. It would help to see the generated sql from the error message and a cfdump of all the variables used in that query.

Comment: *Datatypes are set properly.* Are you 100% positive the cfsqltypes match up with the column data types?

Comment: I edited original post with more info. Leigh, I will double check datatypes now.

Comment: Billedfees Data_type: RBID(int, null)

Comment: Your just missing a comma in your SQL statement before the last cfqueryparam tag.

Comment: Lol, just noticed that myself. Good spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can already access that variable by using this

```
<cfoutput>#myResult.identitycol#</cfoutput>
<Cfset rbid = myResult.identitycol>
```

Since you're using MSSQL whatever you name your result will have the `.identitycol` property.

I believe if you use mysql, oracle, access, it may be something different (as of cf9), but I think they standardized it in cf10.

---

**Update:**

The cause of the error is that you are missing a comma in front of the `RBID` field. Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
<cftransaction>

    <cfset NextBillingDate = DateAdd(FrequencyUnit, FrequencyDuration, DateCompleted)>

    <cfquery name="recbilling" datasource="#request.dsn#" result="myResult">
        INSERT INTO RBilling 
        (
          CID
          , UserID
          , DateCompleted
          , ClientID
          , Title
          , Qty
          , Rate
          , Taxable
          , Description
          , NextBillingDate
          , FrequencyUnit
          , FrequencyDuration
          , ProjectID
        )
        VALUES 
        (
          <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#UserID#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#DateCompleted#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ClientID#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#text0#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#Qty#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#text2#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" value="#Taxable#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" value="#text1#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#NextBillingDate#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FrequencyUnit#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FrequencyDuration#">
          , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">
       )
    </cfquery>

    <cfset RBID = myResult.identitycol>

    <cfquery name="submithourssubmit" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        INSERT INTO Billedfees (
            CID
            , UserID
            , DateCompleted
            , ClientID
            , Title
            , Qty
            , Rate
            , Taxable
            , Description
            , ProjectID
            , RBID
        )
        VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#UserID#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#DateCompleted#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ClientID#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#text0#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#Qty#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_REAL" value="#text2#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" value="#Taxable#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" value="#text1#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">
            , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#RBID#">
        )
    </cfquery>

</cftransaction>
```

Comment: I've adjusted to include what you provided, My SQL string from the error is showing that it's grabbing the RBID I want, which is great, but I'm still getting the @P11 in the error.

Comment: <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ProjectID#">**,**
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#RBID#">

Your missing a comma in front of the RBID field.

Comment: Tip, if you always put the commas at the beginning of the line (before the value) it is easier to spot when you miss one :)

Comment: I updated my answer so you can copy and paste your code into your app.

Comment: @steve - You may want to clean out the excess `#` signs, quotes and cfoutput tags. ie Spit polish the example a shine for "the other" Steve :)

Comment: @Leigh maybe he'll leave me a shiny nickel  :)  Have a good weekend.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: Lol, I hope it is more than a nickel. That is not even enough to buy a virtual beer ;-)

Comment: FYI: Steve, I moved your comment about the missing comma into the answer for better visibility. Also for future readers, I tweaked the query to demonstrate how placing commas at the beginning of the line helps avoid this common error. Hope you do not mind :)

Comment: No, I don't. Thanks again Leigh. And everybody else for their help.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comments, you should not need to use `scope_identity` unless you are running CF7 or earlier. As of CF8, the new identity value will be placed in your [`result`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html) attribute ie "myResult". So the new ID is available in the variable: myResult.IDENTITYCOL.

As an aside, if you *were* going to use `scope_identity`, you must ensure it is invoked on the **same** database connection. So either call it at the end of your insert query:

```
    <cfquery name="addRecord" ...>
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
          INSERT INTO TableName (....)
          VALUES ( ..... );
          SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS RBID;
          SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput> New RBID: #addRecord.RBID#</cfoutput>
```

... -=or=- wrap both cfquery's in a `cftransaction` to ensure you keep the same connection. ie

```
  <cftransaction>
    <cfquery name="addRecord" ...>
          INSERT INTO TableName (....)
          VALUES ( ..... );
    </cfquery>
    <cfquery name="getNewRecord" ...>
          SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS RBID;
    </cfquery>

 </cftransaction>
 <cfoutput> New RBID: #getNewRecord.RBID#</cfoutput>
```